# Drag a UIView along straight path and corners

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

The pattern that I'm going for is that of a gear shifter in a car. It consists of about 9 straight lines at 90 degree angles that I need a user to drag a UIView along.

My first approach was to check the coordinates of the view's center, and if the met certain conditions, enable/disable x/y appropriately. This resulted in a long complex if statement that will be a mess to maintain. It works, for the most part - occasionally it gets stuck, but I know what I would need to do to fix it.

My second idea would be to build a very simple collection of rectangles around my path with a space in the middle just wide enough to allow a square that I would have anchored to the view I want to move. I would then be able to use collision detection to keep the view along the path. This seems like it would work for very basic blocky paths, but wouldn't be feasible with a more complex path.

Are there any other ways to achieve my desired effect?

BTW, here is my super rough and inefficient test for the first scenario:

```
//  The reason we aren't using if else is because we want to allow both x and y movement if they are on a corner.
if(knob.center.x >= 218 && knob.center.x <= 240 && knob.center.y == 140) { 
    //  First line
    canMoveX = TRUE;
    if(translation.x + knob.center.x < 218) { 
        translation.x = knob.center.x - 218; 
    }
    else if(translation.x + knob.center.x > 240) { 
        translation.x = 240 - knob.center.x;
    }

}
if(knob.center.x == 240 && knob.center.y >= 140 && knob.center.y <= 230) { 
    //  Second Line
    canMoveY = TRUE;
    if(translation.y + knob.center.y < 140) { translation.y = knob.center.y - 140; }
    else if(translation.y + knob.center.y > 230) { translation.y = 230 - knob.center.y; }

}

if(knob.center.x >= 224 && knob.center.x <= 240 && knob.center.y == 230) { 
    //  Third Line
    canMoveX = TRUE;
    if(translation.x + knob.center.x < 224) { translation.x = knob.center.x - 224; }
    else if(translation.x + knob.center.x > 240) { translation.x = 240 - knob.center.x; }

} 

if(knob.center.x == 224 && knob.center.y >= 230 && knob.center.y <= 285) { 
    //  Fourth Line
    canMoveY = TRUE;
    if(translation.y + knob.center.y < 230) { translation.y = knob.center.y - 230; }
    else if(translation.y + knob.center.y > 285) { translation.y = 285 - knob.center.y; }

} 

if(knob.center.x >= 205  && knob.center.x <= 224 && knob.center.y == 285) { 
    //  Fifth Line
    canMoveX = TRUE;
    if(translation.x + knob.center.x < 205) { translation.x = knob.center.x - 205; }
    else if(translation.x + knob.center.x > 224) { translation.x = 224 - knob.center.x; }

}  

if(knob.center.x == 205 && knob.center.y >= 285 && knob.center.y <= 337) { 
    //  Sixth Line
    canMoveY = TRUE;
    if(translation.y + knob.center.y < 285) { translation.y = knob.center.y - 285; }
    else if(translation.y + knob.center.y > 337) { translation.y = 337 - knob.center.y; }

} 

if(knob.center.x >= 133 && knob.center.x <= 205 && knob.center.y == 337) { 
    //  Seventh Line
    canMoveX = TRUE;
    if(translation.x + knob.center.x < 133) { translation.x = knob.center.x - 133; }
    else if(translation.x + knob.center.x > 205) { translation.x = 205 - knob.center.x; }
}        

if(canMoveX) {
    [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y)];
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
}
if(canMoveY) {
    [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a solution that fully solved my problem, so I was forced to work with conditionals and points. If anyone has a better solution, I'll be more than happy to mark it as correct in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can do the animation without much of those if..elses,You will have to implement CAKeyFrameAnimation of Core Animation to depict an nanimation along a brezier path .

You will have to define a path and for viewing i have drawn a curve to signify the path and then the object that will  be animated along the path and finally the animation:-

```
     UIBezierPath *yourPath= [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [yourPath moveToPoint:P(x, y)];
    [yourPath addCurveToPoint:P(x1, y1) controlPoint1:P(x, y) controlPoint2:P(x, y)];
//You will have to use addCurveToPoint to add  next turn.

    CAShapeLayer *yourFollowPath= [CAShapeLayer layer];
    yourFollowPath.path = yourPath.CGPath;
    yourFollowPath.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    yourFollowPath.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    yourFollowPath.lineWidth = 50.0;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:yourFollowPath];

    CALayer *moveObject= [CALayer layer];
    moveObject.bounds = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    moveObject.position = P(objXPOs, objYPos);
    moveObject.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"YouImageOfObjectToMove"].CGImage);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:moveObject];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *animate = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"Animating"];
    animate .path = yourPath.CGPath;
    animate .rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
    animate .repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    animate .duration = 11;

[moveObjectaddAnimation:animate forKey:@"gogogo"];
```

This code is just for reference to give you an idea , for the actual program you will have to give the coordinates.

According to our discussion:-

You can implement you logic over the code mentioned above by getting the touchpoints from the user at the object(as you have aleady defined path).you can implement UIGestureRecognizer or even touchesBegan or touchesEnded of UItouch to get the drag like event and then animate if user is still touching else call

```
[yourView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

and get the latest touchpoint and then create another brezierPath from that point if touch resumes.

Comment: This works for animating a view along the path, however I need the user to be able to drag along the path.

Comment: I see where you're going with this - it does make sense, but I worry that it will essentially remove control from the user. I also should have specified that the movement should be bi-directional, allowing the user to move forwards or backwards along the path based on where they drag. I'll play around with your idea, though, to see if I can work in proper drag functionality.